# Magento 2.2.2 - Possible upgrade issues

Tags: magento2, upgrade

Magento 2.2.2 released today with Fixes and enhancements.

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.2.2CE.html

Let me know if anyone is facing some issues while upgrading to Magento 2.2.2?

What other issues are you facing during this upgrade?

Comment: Internal server error when upgrade via composer.